Will it be possible to prevent cancer by introducing ECC on genome?
Could it be possible to drastically improve DNA repair capabilities by introducing error-correcting codes into the human genome? Would it be feasible to reduce the probability of cancer while slightly increasing lifespan?
Of course, the process of decoding a copy of one strand of DNA before transcripting DNA to mRNA would also need to be added through genetic engineering.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

“Error correcting codes” could apply to hundreds of very different biological processes, and most come down to “this thing miraculously happens without consequence.” Everything has a consequence. I need more specificity so I can tell you what yours is.

@DWKraus I mean exclusively in information theory. Hamming code or something. https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Error_correction_code

We have some already, more than mice do, and not as much as E.Coli. What we have is sophisticated beyond my scant understanding, but it seems like a tough question to answer without specifics of how what you're asking about would work. To me the answer would seem to be, yes - if your specific mechanism does that then it can do that. Damned if I can see how it would work though.

Note that this still wouldn't entirely eliminate cancer. The genome might be entirely intact, with the problem being that the portions responsible for regulating cell replication are simply disabled.

Yes, in theory, but you'd need also to reengineer the whole reproductive process; the foetus has a different DNA than both parents. Also, consider that any reading failure from the error correcting system would kill the cell; you might be exchanging cancer with a wasting disease.

Note that any error correction mechanism will be coded as DNA too, so should be resistant to mutations. And if a 100% effective error correction mechanism could be devised, it would basically eliminate the evolution of completely new traits altogether, leaving only the possibility of remixing already existing traits via sexual reproduction.

Any error correcting mechanism has to consider the causes of errors. We have cancers which appear to be caused by bacterial infections, virus infections, as well as the random changes induced by the radioactivity around us. Some viruses inject their DNA into ours. Detecting and correcting that would be a major challenge for an "error correcting" code.

@DavidR viruses could even conceivably exploit the additional error correcting machinery to achieve that...tricking it into thinking the viral code is what is supposed to be there, or just modifying that machinery to bypass the checks and inject the viral code.

bio-mechanics means something unrelated to this post, so I removed that tag and added transhumanism which involved modifying humans often genetically, although also by other means, to enhance them.

@DavidR That's simply unreadable. Cell will assume plaintext DNA as ECC DNA and will decode wrongfully. duplication of virus will fail as it becomes random noise. Unless someone develop bio-weapon...

I don't understand how this is about WorldBuilding, rather than any of the tags attached? I stand to be corrected, and my understanding is that SE WB is necessarily about fiction

If you're interested in genetic modifcations to suppress cancer, you might want to have a look at elephants and whales. Due to their large mass (and therefore high cell count) they're at a much higher statistical risk for cancer-causing mutations. In spite of this, they are able to live long healthy lives with lower cancer rates than humans.
There have been a number of studies to try to figure out why large mammals don't immediately get cancer and die. For elephants, one puzzle piece has been found already: they have extra copies of the tumor-suppressing gene TP53. Humans have this gene too, and when it's functioning correctly, it does its job rather well. 50-60% of tumors in humans involve a mutation in TP53 1. So Elephants have about 20 copies of TP53 instead of 1. If you're genetically modifying humans to increase cancer resistance, that sounds like an easy first step.
With whales we don't know as much, but there's certainly potential for in-world research that finds new cancer suppressing genes there too. That seems like a much more plausible approach than using man-made information theory (fun as that would be!).

This is mostly due to cancer turning and attacking other cancer at a certain size. So whales and elephants get cancer - all the time, but it eats itself if aggressive and denatures into binding tissue or enclosed benign cancerous masses (contained similar to a cyst).

@pica those sound like interesting mechanism.  Do you have e any links handy?

@NBrouwer: They're called hypertumors. Basically, the cancer gets cancer.

@joshua thanks - never heard of them before. Looks like they're isn't much empirical evidence for then yet but strong reasons from theoretical and mathematical models to hypothesize they exist!

@NBrouwer: There is empirical evidence they exist. There's no empirical evidence as to whether or not that's an effective anti-cancer mechanism.

Cellular biology already has error-correcting mechanisms that are far more sophisticated than simple codes like checksums or parity bits.
For instance, one of the most common replication errors is the so-called "frameshift error". DNA codes for proteins in three-base "codons" that are read off by the cellular machinery that processes it. In a frameshift error, this machinery attaches to the wrong place or miscounts, and so instead of a sequence of, say, [ATG][ATG][A...] it reads [...A][TGA][TGA]. Naively this seems like it should be capable of generating a huge variety of junk proteins, but in practice this is not that common. The danger of having long junk proteins leads to a selection pressure in favor of genes that are resistant to frameshift errors. Either they have "hidden" stop codons (which tell the cell to stop reading the DNA strand there) which are only encountered when frameshifted and lead to short, meaningless proteins that are easily recycled, or the frameshifted proteins are close enough analogs of the intended protein that it's not hazardous to have them around.
So, the short answer to your question is: over millions of years, the low-hanging fruit of the genome has been pretty thoroughly picked over. You'd need to come up with something quite sophisticated to outdo the systems life already has.

Frame challenge: Nature never needed humans to live past the age of 50 so there were little evolutionary pressure to resist cancer at later age.

One extreamly simple way to strengthen this as an error detection code, but probably too inefficient to have evolved: Use 4 bases per codon, rather than 3. And have most of the codons code for stops, such that any frameshift of baseswap would result in a stop codon much earlier.

Isn't it just a file system or tarball?

@cadence minor point - frameshift mutations originate during DNA replication, resulting in downstream consequences when a gene expressed and protein made.

@Tentacles3587 I'm not sure what you mean by "just a file system" but I wouldn't consider that a particularly good analogy for DNA. For instance, DNA has no centralized store of where genes begin the way most filesystems do. Nor is there a central processor that is responsible for accessing genes - instead there are many independent enzymes transcribing different parts of the genome at any given time, with no knowledge of each other.

en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inode filesystem knows where all fragments of file starts and end. Anyway, much simpler and appropriate analogy is null character. Or zerofill some remaining part

This answer ignores the level of sophistication of state-of-the-art error correction codes (e.g. Huffman codes and Reed-Solomon codes). They are vastly superior to things like parity bits in terms or error correction capabilities even though they are already several decades old.

@Dreamer That's not the fundamental difference. The problem is the software or document you're downloading over Wi-Fi or LTE is needs to be bit-exact, or it will fail. Biological systems are very much the opposite: they operate with a ton of noise and highly unreliably, and rely on concepts like massive molecular-level parallelism to operate correctly. Evolution means billions of people with faulty genes will get cancer and drop dead.

@user1937198 There’s already a nontrivial amount of redundancy, so having more is very much less than ideal. Methionine and tryptophan are the only cases represented by only a single codon, all other possibilities (including stop codons) have 2-4 (out of 64 possible) codons that represent them.

@Dreamer The molecular machinery required for that level of complexity is not exactly light on energy requirements, which means it’s likely to be selected against pretty strongly, especially since most people would be passing on their genes long before the benefits of that level of correction would show themselves.

@Dreamer Also, I think you mean Hamming codes, not Huffman coding. Huffman coding is a data compression algorithm, and provides no error detection or correction at all.

@alamar that would actually be an interesting question: does having living (grand)parents increase the changes of your offspring?

@DonQuiKong Before modernity, you will be able to rear your children and your grandkids and die peacefully at 60. Life would excert more wear and tear on your body, so we live up to 80 now but that's it.

@alamar: The challenge isn't whether nature's existing solution can prevent cancer completely. (In a sense, it does to a large extent just not completely.) The challenge is how you can create a credible fantasy mechanism that does better than nature, and ideally with the right trade off. ie. If there is cost, then most of the cost should not be spent on duplicating existing functions in nature. It's ofc not right to say it is impossible since we don't know everything about nature's DNA solutions. But what one needs is way beyond simple ECC. Also of note is the direct linkage between

DNA replication or translation errors and cancer assumed for such discussions. It is a useful assumption for discussion. But obviously cancer, or aging, is a lot more complicated than that.

A couple viruses have long overlapping frameshifed sequences. These can't change.

The great thing about the double helix is how it can be replicated. Take the strand, spit it, put the complementary acid opposite the nold one to get a new double helix.
That's a simplification, of course. But the mechanism would get even more complicated if the proteins involved in the duplication had to do complex maths on top of that. For a fictional biology, you could describe Terran biochemists being puzzled and amazed by the complexity of those cells. A few crackpots might even claim that the cells are artificially constructed nanomachines, not the result of natural evolution.

I think you can just dupe DNAs without decode error-correction code. Reproduction would be quite complicated though.

Error correcting codes do not necessarily need complex math, otherwise they would be unusable for computer memory. (Because whatever math is needed has to be done very very fast.) A little bit of slightly non-trivial math is required for space-efficient error correcting codes, but if storage space is not an issue then simply storing each codon in triplicate would easily allow detecting and correcting all single-base errors.

I think I remember a story of an alien with a triple helix, such that three parts have to agree in complement for reliable replication. That would give extra error correction. Of course it wouldn't be DNA anymore as it would need different chemicals.

The mechanism for duping DNA and reproduction are relatively unrelated. The DNA strands are not mixed at all in fertilization but the earlier process of meiosis in the parent when the gametes are formed. As such the duping process could be significantly more complicated, whilst retaining standard sexual reproduction.

@user1937198, I'm talking about DNA replication during cell division.

All life does this to a greater or lesser extend.  Fungi do it to a much greater extent than most animals so that they can safely pump cytoplasm around between cells -- which is how they can pop up relatively massive structures like mushrooms in a matter of hours.
So, yes, you can add more error correction to a genome.  It will cut down on any varieties of cancer that are caused by mis-copied or otherwise damaged DNA during replication, and it will give much greater resistance to viral infection.
The downside is that it won't do anything for any varieties of cancer that are caused by genetically normal cells operating in the wrong "mode" and misbehaving, and the more you lock down your genome, the slower your adaptation rate will be, and the narrower your reproductive compatibility will be.  (Of course, if you have genetic engineering and are this good at it, you probably don't care about the last two.)
It probably won't help lifespan all that much.  A lot of the decisions about growth and development and repair of a body seem to be timer-based.  As time goes by the timers go out of range and the ability to make repairs wanes.  But you have good genetic engineering, so adding in some reset points where the body regrows various organs from scratch could do the trick.  Or possibly regrows the whole thing except the brain in some kind of molting process.

Isn't a big part of the "ceases to repair itself" the existence of telomeres which limit the amount that a cell can reproduce? Those are, as I understand, a anti-cancer "measure", if some other system keeps cancer at bay, they wouldn't need this mechanism anyway.

@htmlcoderexe  It's not the existence of the telomeres, it's that they wear out. You can think of them kind of like the leader on an old filmstrip. Every time you load the film into the projector you have some chance of damaging the end as you thread it in. So we manufacture them with some blank leader so you can just trim it off when you mangle it. But eventually your trimming will bite into the actual film and then you start losing video. Unfortunately, there's also some indication that telomere length gets used as a crude timer, so just preventing them from shortening may have side-effects.

Like the preamble in ethernet frames, got it - so this is actually their functionality and the "shortening as a replication limit" is a useful(?) side-effect of this?

@htmlcoderexe  Pretty much.  Useful because a lead-in track for DNA replication is absolutely necessary, and an organism-wide clock is highly useful for synchronizing growth and development.  But, at the same time, rather a dodgy hack that's only acceptable because evolution doesn't care about the lifespan of the individual, only reproductive fitness.

Different species of animals have dramatically different cancer rates even when they are in the same environment. As explained in one scientific study:

50 to 90% of aged mice die of cancer, while in humans this number is
approximately 23%. Less is known about cancer in wild animals.
However, several species are known to be extremely cancer resistant.
These include the naked mole rat, blind mole rat, elephant and bowhead
whale. The age of onset of cancer also varies greatly depending on the
lifespan of the species.

This is driven by some aspect of their DNA, although not necessary crude error correction codes. For example, according to the same study:

Rangarajan and colleagues . . . showed that two hits are needed for
transformation of mouse fibroblasts, namely inactivation of either
Trp53 or Rb1 and an activating mutation in Hras, while five hits are
needed to transform human fibroblasts (inactivation of TP53, RB1,
protein phosphatase 2A (PP2A), and constitutive activation of
telomerase and HRAS). Although tumors more frequently arise in
epithelial cells rather than fibroblasts, this analysis suggests that
humans have evolved much more robust anticancer defenses than mice.

In principle, the same DNA features that lead to low cancer rates in animals that have low cancer rates would also reduce cancer rates in humans. As another answer notes, adding "extra copies of the tumor-suppressing gene TP53" is one promising possibility along these lines.
The problem is that (from the same source): "Evolutionary pressure to evolve efficient anticancer mechanisms is very strong."
So, if an animal hasn't evolved anticancer mechanisms to a greater extent, despite this strong evolutionary pressure for hundreds of thousands or millions of years, this is probably because the anticancer mechanisms would interfere with some other fitness enhancing trait in that animal. Otherwise, all animals would have evolved traits leading to the very low cancer rates that are currently seen in only a handful of animals.
Until the genetics and biochemistry of living things, in general, and humans, in particular, are better understood, tweaking the genome to provide better cancer protection poses a hard to quantify risk that doing so will lead to other, unknown problems.
Of course, a less ethical fictional genetic engineer could simply "f- around and find out", and use informed trial and error to figure out what works best to reduce cancer incidents in future genetically modified humans at an acceptable cost in fitness reducing side effects (some of which might not even be fitness reducing in a modern environment, even though they were fitness reducing when cancer preventing traits evolved in humans and their ancestors), knowing that many subjects will suffer serious fitness reducing side effects as a result of the genetic modification.
Many notable advances in medicine (for example, the discovery of an effective way to treat fistulas by Dr. J. Marion Sims) are derived from this kind of unethical treatment of human subjects in medical research. The claim, which some historians dispute, is as follows:

Vesicovaginal fistula was a catastrophic complication of childbirth
among 19th century American women. The first consistently successful
operation for this condition was developed by Dr J Marion Sims, an
Alabama surgeon who carried out a series of experimental operations on
black slave women between 1845 and 1849. Numerous modern authors have
attacked Sims's medical ethics, arguing that he manipulated the
institution of slavery to perform ethically unacceptable human
experiments on powerless, unconsenting women.

Using genetic modification in a crude trial and error approach to try to identify cancer resistance traits could easily give rise to a similar scandalous violation of medical ethics.

Evolution doesn't care about the lifespan of the individual. There is strong pressure to avoid cancers that inhibit the ability to reproduce. Cancers which do not would be subject only to indirect selection pressure as evolution tries to suppress the ones which do. It might be interesting to see if there's a correlation between cancer suppressing adaptations and length of reproductive viability.

And to introduce error checks does not fix things automatically. You just know there is a error detection and correction encoding. Like this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reed%E2%80%93Solomon_error_correction
It allows, for a space tradeoff, to restore damaged parts.
But it can not be done at the moment. The reason being is, that DNA is the ultimate spaghetti code. As in - its full of "junk" DNA, which is not useless, we just don't get what it is used for. Remove the junk, clean it up- and you get something that is not a human. Means- the shape of the useless part, like a packaging, is helping the cell heap called human, to take the shape it does. Means when https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cellular_differentiation is happening, the organs and shapes do not only develop due to hormonal triggers and dna/rna expressions, but also due to the whole messy systems rolling the missed steak around.
For this to work out, you would have to do a total rewrite of the biological system called human. If you did something like this with https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Synthetic_biology from the ground up, you could add that as a self-repair mechanism. But we are still very far away from that.
Whats could be relatively fast possible is- a duplicate reader. Basically a virus, gets injected into a cell, where it makes a DNA copy. And it proofreads everytime DNA is transcribed - and if the proofread fails it just clogs up the cell and thus the whole thing dies.

There are some mechanisms that do basically that already built into the cell.  Obviously they don't have an entire backup copy of the DNA, but they do try to kill the cell when there are too many transcription errors.  One of the key things that leads to cancer is these mechanisms being suppressed. Nicotine, for example, increases cancer rates not by being a carcinogen itself, but by suppressing the cellular apoptosis reaction that tries to eliminate cancer cells.

Knowing more now, one could do a sort of reed solomon https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reed%E2%80%93Solomon_error_correction in junk DNA, as long as alpha fold https://alphafold.ebi.ac.uk/ can assert it keeps its ineraction shape. I guess this is how it feels to be in a pre singularity society, before its plucked from the simulation to "pass the butter"

Oh, there are all kinds of error correction you could put into it. And it has quite a bit built in already. The main reason to use DNA instead of RNA is error correction for starters. But this will only stop cancers that arise from random damage. There are a great many ways the multicellular orchestration can go wrong that don't involve damage. One of the more common, canine cancers, for example, is also an STD and started its "life" some 20K years ago as a few cells that broke off another dog and managed to keep living in their new home.

This is not going to be enough. Even the most sophisticated error-correction system is going to be ultimately overwhelmed by the sheer amount of carcinogenic junk our cells get filled with over time.
It would be kinda like trying to use code correction on a script while the hardware that the script is running on is gunked with dust and garbage.
To significantly lower the risk of cancer, and to meaningfully increase lifespan, you need to find a way to efficiently clean up the cellular gunk, free radicals and metabolic trash that the mitochondria generate. Otherwise, the error-fixing mechanism is going to be ultimately overwhelmed, or the whole cell is going to crap out, and you cannot produce more cells infinitely.

This answer could be improved by going more into detail about what "overwhelmed by the sheer amount of carcinogenic junk" means. In principle, correctly configured error correction codes could handle arbitrarily large numbers of carcinogenic mutations.
The limiting factor is rather that cancer could disable the error correction mechanism itself even while the error correction data stays present. This answer hints at that issue, but does not clearly explain it.

I don't understand the premise that it is fundamentally impossible for an error correcting system to keep up. If the error correcting system is not sophisticated enough, just make it more sophisticated and more redundant. Even if the system really is inevitably doomed to fail at some point, so long as that time point is generally beyond the human lifespan, it doesn't matter. You can't truly eliminate the chance of errors, but you can make the likelihood arbitrarily low with an arbitrarily good ECC, and make the average time-to-error arbitrarily long.

@Dreamer, Im not versed enough i cellular chemistry to explain it well. Based on several articles on Astral Codex, all of which seem well researched, it seems that the ultimate reason for both cancer and cell senescence is the increased amount of Reactive Oxygen Species that come from suboptimal glycolisis. These ROS then tend to damage pretty much every cellular system in one way or another, including causing mutogenesis of all processes, even the error-correction process itself. Even if the Error-correction was super efficient, at some point the whole code would be incorrectible hash.

@NuclearHoagie Then I think we need to agree what counts as effective gain in lifespan. 10 years? 50years? How arbitrary good we want the ECC to be; scientifically plausible or plot magic? Even if we somehow made the ECC impossibly perfect, but ROS-related senescence not prevented, this will not lead to cellular life extension, but something more akin to zombiefication. You would get cell lines that divide with zero error, but are effectively unable to function, and need to get their energy from plot magic.

As both the other answers currently points out, you will have to work hard to outperform the current solution.
But it is possible.  It is, however, very deep future tech.  We do not know enough today to even begin to tinker with this system.
Protein synthesis is a very fundamental to how cells work and adding error correction would mean redesigning it almost from scratch.  It would cost more energy to run.
Still, it is something that far future humanity might do.
An easier fix would be to find and eliminate those genes that increase cancer risk.  It is well known that cancer risk runs in families. Make that stop and we will have won decades of extra life.

See also:  Lazarus Long.  ;)

No.
The genome is so minuscule, and so extremely charged with electric potential, and so engrossed in surface vibration that there are no machines available to edit it. To create such a machine would require such lathing or various cutting and grasping/holding that it would require in itself that minuscule of process. Answer: No.
As an example: Consider the most advanced Central Processing Unit CPU that is being manufactured today. If you look at the lines of it connecting the transistors and at the transistors themselves via an electron microscope you observe a scene similar to a line painted by a falling-down drunk. And these are the most advanced delicate machining processes in the world. If these are so sloppy and they are the most accurate, while being so distorted, then editing a genome is far beyond that in complexity.
No.

Did you really just dismiss the entire field of nanotechnology, because it's basically "too small?" No.

Of course there is molecular machinery that can operate on a genome, that's exactly what occurs when DNA gets unzipped and replicated in normal cellular division. Genome editing has been possible for over 50 years. What you claim is impossible has been done for decades and has seen major advances in recent years - look up CRISPR. How tiny we can make transistors has very little to do with how one edits a genome. By the logic used here, most molecular chemistry should also be impossible, simply because molecules are smaller than transistors, but that clearly isn't the case.

@Xen2050, Thank you for noticing. Almost exactly. Yes I did almost. You read that almost right. I did just dismiss the manufacturing processes required to edit at nano sizing because it is basically "too small." You almost got that correct. I did not dismiss cutting at nano sizing which can be done via laser. I did not dismiss disassembly at atomic sizing which can be done via chemical interactions. I did dismiss manufacturing at that size level. You almost got it correct. Thank you.

@Nuclear Hoagie, From sciencedirect.com [https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/S0952791514001563?via%3Dihub] Nowhere in there is any description of manufacturing. It describes CRISPR as being a natural biological process, not a manufacturing process. Thank you for supporting my statements.

Did you read that link? CRISPR uses natural processes for genome editing. "Notwithstanding the natural immune role of CRISPR–Cas systems in prokaryotes, the most visible and significant recent research has arguably been centered around the repurposing of the Cas machinery for genome editing and transcriptional control in eukaryotes. Indeed, repurposing of the programmable Cas9 endonuclease has revolutionized genome editing and open new avenues for transcriptional control with unprecedented ease and flexibility."

Even if physical manufacturing methods were the way we edited DNA -- which it's not, there are far simpler ways -- you'd still be behind the times.  There are some technologies being developed that allow 3d printing at basically the molecular level.  They're not in use for computer chips (yet) because it's still far too expensive.  But give it another twenty years...  And in a hundred it won't surprise me if atomic-level assembly has become a thing.

@Nuclear Hoagie, It still describes CRISPR as being a natural biological process, not a manufacturing process. "Research"is not the same as manufacturing. Those are two different things. The word linkresearch is derived from the Middle French "recherche", which means "to go about seeking" Or, "Scientific research is a systematic way of gathering data and harnessing curiosity." Seeking and curiosity. Your quoted sentence started with being based upon "research," and not in any manner on actual manufacturing. You have quoted proving my point.

@Perkins, "technologies being developed." "Being developed" is not the same as "have been developed," and even further from manufacturing capability. I thought this was supposed to be a site for logic, not for pretending that dreams are fact. That is, unless the responses have been for some dream world building. In the later case, I see your point. Some sci-fi authors had a lot of dream worlds that resulted in lots of books and sales. Some were based upon technologies "being developed." I see that point. Some people might even have believed them at the time. "Being developed," I get it.

@LineItem The "worldbuilding" stack exchange kind of is where budding sci-fi authors, among others, kick around ideas...  And nano-scale manufacturing has big enough payoffs that I doubt anybody's giving up on it any time soon.  It's an extension of what we're doing for our computer chips, broadened out to other kinds of molecules and at ever finer resolution.. We went from 2d to 3d semiconductor construction many moons ago at this point. We're already getting transistors so small that it's hard to keep the electrons from leaking out of them. And experimental molecular-scale printers do exist.

@Perkins, Thank you for that information. "experimental molecular-scale printers do exist." That is interesting.

@LineItem The first CRISPR therapy has already been approved by the FDA, and even more are in ongoing trials. Casgevy is an approved, commercially available product which can be purchased by an average consumer - clearly manufacturing, not research. The simple fact is that what you claim is impossible is already being done - the thrust of this answer is that "a genome is too small to edit", which is provably false.

@NuclearHoagie,  From the FDA:
Reference: https://www.fda.gov/news-events/press-announcements/fda-approves-first-gene-therapies-treat-patients-sickle-cell-disease .
"Today, the U.S. Food and Drug Administration approved two milestone treatments, Casgevy and Lyfgenia,
representing the first cell-based gene therapies[...]."
"Lyfgenia is a cell-based gene therapy. Lyfgenia uses a lentiviral vector[...]."
Lets look at Casgevy.
Reference: https://investors.vrtx.com/news-releases/news-release-details/vertex-announces-us-fda-approval-casgevytm-exagamglogene .

@NuclearHoagie, "CASGEVY™ (exagamglogene autotemcel [exa-cel]), a CRISPR/Cas9 gene-edited cell therapy[...]."
Notice the "gene-edited." Not machine edited. Not computer edited. Not super tiny knife and super tiny tweezers cutting and adjusting the DNA. "gene-edited." Using viruses to do the work.
Lets look at Lyfgenia.
Reference: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lentiviral_vector_in_gene_therapy .

@NuclearHoagie, "Lentiviral vectors in gene therapy is a method by which genes can be inserted, modified, or deleted in organisms using lentiviruses."
Notice the "using lentiviruses." "lentiviruses". Not by computer or machine or any variation thereof. Using viruses to do the work.
"Lentiviruses are a family of viruses[...]."
You have supported my statement even though you said that it was, "provably false." I think your arguments might be reverse logic intended to bring light to the false claim of DNA being edited by man.
OK. Reverse logic. You supported my statements.

@NuclearHoagie, Summary: Casgevy is "cell-based" using a lentiviral vector which is also cell-based. Lyfgenia also is cell based "using lentiviruses." The virus does the work on the target DNA.  A virus does the work. There is a difference between a virus and a machine. Maybe you might have wanted the general public to get this information and now they have it. They could have looked it up themselves. But this is OK.

@Perkins, "experimental molecular-scale printers do exist." Electron microscopes exist, and it is possible to vector electrons via a laser, therefore printing with high velocity electrons seems to be a reasonable way to heat up an endostrait causing a change in color, or as you mentioned earlier, "3d printing at basically the molecular level". Nice comment. A valid consideration for manufacturing. Although we used light for 3d printing more than 20 years ago which is more accurate, but useful information maybe for deeper penetrating printing. I think that I like you.
